# How to define 'self' in python script

Tags: python

i am just learning about classes and methods in python and i have a script that i am not sure why it isn't working. The script accepts an integer from the user from the console and then for the number of student accounts desired, it asks the user for the first name, last name, age, and username. It then is supposed to print the list of students and their default password. Lastly it is supposed to calculate and print the average age of the students that were entered. Here is my script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def calcAverageAge(age_list):
    average=sum(age_list) / len(age_list)
    print("The average age of the students is:", average)
def validateAge():
    while age < 15 or age > 45:
         age=int(input("Age must be between 15 and 45"))

class CIT383Student: # class definition
    def __init__(self,first,last,age,username,current_password):#contsructor
        self.first_name=first # instantiate object create with first name, last name, age, username, and password
        self.last_name=last
        self.User_age=age
        self.uname=username
        self.pw=current_password
    def defPassword(self): # Create default password for each user
        import time  #timestamp for default password
        firstChar=self.first_name[0]
        lastChar=self.last_name[0]
        ts=time.time()
        self.defPassword = (firstChar + lastChar + ts)    # compute the default password for the user

    #def displayUsers(self):
    #    print(self.first_name, self.last_name, self.User_age, self.uname, self.pw)


age_list = []
student_list =[]
studentNumber = int(input("Please Enter the number of student accounts: "))
for _ in range(studentNumber): #For each student
    first = input("please enter the first name of the student: ")
    last = input("Please enter the last name of the student: ")
    age = input("please enter the age of the student")
    username = input("Please enter username of the student")
    CIT383Student.defPassword()
    student=CIT383Student(first,last,age,username,current_password)
    student_list.append(student)

for student in student_list:
    CIT383Student.displayUsers()
    print("\n")

calcAverageAge()
```

The error i am receiving is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "filepath", line 36, in <module>
        CIT383Student.defPassword(self)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Sorry if this is too long of a question. I am just stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: to define a lass you have to do `class MyClass():`

Comment: @LeonardoScotti that is not true

Comment: The 36th line, `CIT383Student.defPassword()` will raise `TypeError: defPassword() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`, not a `NameError`.

Comment: @Timhenn98 next time please include the **full** stack trace

Answer (score 6):

In line 36, you call

```
CIT383Student.defPassword()
```

You have to instantiate the `CIT383Student` class first. `defPassword()` is an instance method, and hence expects to be called from an instance, while you call it from the class itself.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an instance of the class `CIT383Student` before you can call `defPassword()` on it since `defPassword()` is not a static method.

```
c = CIT383Student(first, last, age, username, current_password)
c.defPassword()
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to instantiate the class first before executing instance method.
- You can not call defPassword method (instance method) like class method.

```
    student=CIT383Student(first,last,age,username,current_password)
    student.defPassword()
```

- you have another problem in the code.  You missed to define current_password variable. Probably you need to add this code.

```
current_password = input("Please enter current password")
```